# tensor.shape return a list of None values when using tf.keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

I have a function which accepts a tensor and calculates the num_classes variable from the shape of this tensor using an equation which looks something like this:

```
num_classes = tensor.shape[4] - 5.
```

now if I call this function standalone wthi random input , it works just fine, but as this function is part of a logic which computes some metric while runnnig the model on validation data after every epoch , it fails and outputs this error:

```
File "train.py", line 142, in <module>
    main()
  File "train.py", line 120, in main
    train(input_size,
  File "train.py", line 81, in train
    face_detector.fit(train_data_generator ,
  File "/home/yogeesh/yogeesh/tf2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1215, in fit
    val_logs = self.evaluate(
  File "/home/yogeesh/yogeesh/tf2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1501, in evaluate
    tmp_logs = self.test_function(iterator)
  File "/home/yogeesh/yogeesh/tf2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 885, in __call__
    result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
  File "/home/yogeesh/yogeesh/tf2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 933, in _call
    self._initialize(args, kwds, add_initializers_to=initializers)
  File "/home/yogeesh/yogeesh/tf2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 759, in _initialize
    self._stateful_fn._get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(  # pylint: disable=protected-access
  File "/home/yogeesh/yogeesh/tf2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 3066, in _get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected
    graph_function, _ = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
  File "/home/yogeesh/yogeesh/tf2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 3463, in _maybe_define_function
    graph_function = self._create_graph_function(args, kwargs)
  File "/home/yogeesh/yogeesh/tf2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 3298, in _create_graph_function
    func_graph_module.func_graph_from_py_func(
  File "/home/yogeesh/yogeesh/tf2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py", line 1007, in func_graph_from_py_func
    func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
  File "/home/yogeesh/yogeesh/tf2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 668, in wrapped_fn
    out = weak_wrapped_fn().__wrapped__(*args, **kwds)
  File "/home/yogeesh/yogeesh/tf2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py", line 994, in wrapper
    raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
TypeError: in user code

    /home/yogeesh/yogeesh/tf2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py:1330 test_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    /home/yogeesh/yogeesh/object_detection/Yolov3_tf2/metrics/mAP.py:102 update_state  *
        box_objects = tf_postprocessing.post_process(predictions ,
    /home/yogeesh/yogeesh/object_detection/Yolov3_tf2/postprocessing/tf_postprocessing.py:137 post_process  *
        all_gt = modify_locs(ground_truth , scale_anchors , gt = True)
    /home/yogeesh/yogeesh/object_detection/Yolov3_tf2/postprocessing/tf_postprocessing.py:35 modify_locs  *
        modified_loc = pp_utils.modify_locs_util(localizations , this_scale_anchor , ground_truth = gt)
    /home/yogeesh/yogeesh/object_detection/Yolov3_tf2/postprocessing/tf_utils.py:20 modify_locs_util  *
        num_classes = localizations.shape[4] - 5

    TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'NoneType' and 'int'

2021-10-21 18:33:00.783103: W tensorflow/core/kernels/data/generator_dataset_op.cc:107] Error occurred when finalizing GeneratorDataset iterator: Failed precondition: Python interpreter state is not initialized. The process may be terminated.
     [[{{node PyFunc}}]]
```

This happens only while training , using tf.keras.model.fit function where it runs a overridden test_Step function in "evaluate" call.

this is the function where i am getting an error.

```
def modify_locs_util(localizations , anchors , img_shape = [416, 416] , ground_truth = False):
    # localizations.shape : [batch_size , grid_size , grid_size , 3 , 7] (for this dataset)
    #  where grid_size can be 13,26,52 (Yolov3 model).
    locs_shape = tf.shape(localizations)
    grid_shape = locs_shape[1:3]
    num_anchors = locs_shape[3]
    num_classes = locs_shape[4] - 5
    strides = [img_shape[0] // grid_shape[0], img_shape[1] // grid_shape[1]]
    cell_grid = comman_utils.gen_cell_grid(grid_shape[0] , grid_shape[1] , num_anchors)
```

weird thing is , if i print the shape of localizations there result comes something as this:

```
(None, 13, 13, 3, 7)
(None, 26, 26, 3, 7)
(None, 52, 52, 3, 7)
(None, None, None, None, None)
```

as you can see, first 3 times the shape is fine , but i dont why is it calling again (it should call this fucntion only 3 times) and now it is referring the shape as all None's. Its almost like its doing a architechure check first to figure out shapes but even then static dims shouldnt be None.

Comment: @AloneTogether yes it was , thanks . Though after going in depth of why some things were happeining , i understood that tf does tracing multiple times for graph construction and thus is unknown of the tensor shapes if not complete static. so tf.shape helps us to get pass the compilation and create graph properly.

Comment: @AloneTogether since my reputation is less i cant upvote. been trying to since yesterday.

Comment: No problem.... then some time later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try the following code:

```
num_classes = tf.shape(tensor)[4] - 5.
```

which will be evaluated when the fit(*) method is called.

Comment: this worked in a way that , now tf is observing this a sub fucntion where shape is returning a tensor itself. so thanks for this. But printing this is giving me a tensor of StridedSlice op whereas i want to access the actual value instead, Is there a way to do that ? @AloneTogether

Comment: i have added more details regarding ur query.

Comment: Please create a new question with your new query, since your original question: "tensor.shape return a list of None values when using tf.keras" was answered.